# Windows WebStorm: This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers

Tags: linux, windows, unix, character-encoding, webstorm

I like Windows as working platform, and linux as server: so why I'm using **Windows based WebStorm** and **Debian Linux as server**. But now have this error:

`This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers.`

[image]

Please help me to solve it, I want to continue using Windows WebStorm, I already changed encoding in WebStorm and resaved file, but err still there, and its improssible to change editors to convert encodings, want to stay with mine WebStorm.

[image]

*as you can see in screenshot everything is changed, please help me to find solution. Thanks*

Comment: Are you able to share a reduced copy of the file that still triggers the error? I suspect that jshint is not detecting the correct encoding from the byte-order mark or an explicit declation.

Comment: 1) Your code does not show what character that is. 2) This IDE does not really allow to *convert* encodings (it can but it's rather limited and not obvious). For such tasks (convert from one encoding to another) you *better* use some another tool (e.g. Notepad++). But sure -- you can always open any file in specific/different encoding (and it will be saved in the same encoding) 3) It's possible that linter complains on some invisible character (usually happens when copy-pasting text from web browser); if so -- please try "Zero Width Characters locator" plugin